# What does [a|b|c] evaluate to in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog, pipe, iso-prolog, cons

The pipe operator in prolog returns one or more atomic Heads and a Tail list.

```
?- [a,b,c] = [a,b|[c]].
true.
```

Nesting multiple pipes in a single match can be done similar to this:

```
?- [a,b,c] = [a|[b|[c]]].
true.
```

What does the statement `[a|b|c]` infer about a, b and c?

**EDIT**

So far, all I can deduce is:

```
?- [a,b,c] = [a|b|c].
false.
```

I am more interested in any *techniques* to find the answer rather than to answer this borderline useless question.

**EDIT2**
I'm clearly not too familiar with prolog, a simple assignment answered my question...

```
?- R = [a|b|c].
R = [a| (b'|'c)].
```

What exactly is going on with `(b'|'c)`?

Comment: Looks like homework to me. If so, please tag it as that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Prolog, but, uhh, why can't you just write up a quick program to evaluate it?

Comment: Actually no, just an interesting question I stumbled upon while studying for my semester exams at uni: https://secure.csse.uwa.edu.au/run/help3242?p=np&a=99

I did spend awhile getting my question to look nice though, fit for an exam paper? :)

Comment: @Matchu I'm not sure how to work it out beyond the fact that this evaluates to false: 
?- [a,b,c] = [a|b|c].
false.

Comment: What exactly is going on with (b'|'c)

The parentheses are necessary to distinguish '.'(a, '.'(b,c)) from '.'('.'(a,b), c) - the first is a right-skewed tree, the second is left-skewed. The quotes are probably an effort by the Prolog interpreter to ensure that its output can be cut-and-pasted back into itself. (This may be implementation-deprendent; my SWI-Prolog neither expects nor requires that quote.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since I'm your lecturer I, here's my answer.
(Oh, and I can confirm that this isn't homework, it's related to the practice exam).

The syntax `[a|b|c]` actually doesn't seem to be standard Prolog, and some implementations interpret it differently.  (Had I known this I might not have used it.)

Some interpret it as `[a|[b|c]]`.  (As I intended.)

But with SWI Prolog (and probably others):

```
?- [a|b|c] = [a|[b|c]].
false.
```

The `(b '|' c)` is actually constructed using `'|'` rather than `'.'` as a list would be.  So, the the second `|` is not interpreted as being part of constructing a list at all.

To confirm this, the following succeeds:

```
   ?- X=(b|c), [a|b|c] = [a|X].
   X = (b'|'c) .
```

The `'|'` here seems to be a another binary operator on terms just like `'.'`.

Instead of `[a|b|c]` the standard in Prolog is to use `[a,b|c]`.

(I only decided to use `[a|b|c]` in Programming Paradigms because it more directly relates to the notation `a::b::c` from F#, and we only saw a tiny glimpse of Prolog.  In future I guess I'll relate to `[a|[b|c]]` and then give `[a,b|c]` as an abbreviation.)

Comment: Oh, right! So `[a|b|c]` is syntactic sugar for `'.'(a,(b'|'c))`! So the `|` operator differs from `::` in that the tail doesn't strictly need to be a list, just a "thing"? I'm still trying to swallow what exactly it means for a language to **not** have types...

Comment: Technically the `'.'` and the `'|'` are the operators.  Both can be applied to any two terms to create a kind a pair - unlike `::` in F#/ML where the type checker makes sure `::` is only used for pairs of a head and corresponding tail.

`'.'` is nearly always used for lists though, and the syntax `[t1, t2 | t3]` is an abbreviation for `'.'(t1, '.'(t2, t3))`.  If the `t3` is actually `t4 | t5` then that `|` isn't part of the abbreviation, so you get `'.'(t1, '.'(t2, (t4'|'t5)))`.

Comment: Which system did interpret `[a|b|c]` as `[a|[b|c]`? Please see my answer for the standard.

Comment: As you said in your answer,  this was SWI and an older version.  Much older now.

Answer (score 6):

Within ISO-Prolog, `[a|b|c]` is invalid syntax. And in the meantime also within SWI. It seems you used an older version. Some Prolog systems gave this term some interpretation. Alas, they all differed in the very precise way how they interpreted that term. Some as `[(a'|'b)|c]` or `[a|(b'|'c)]` or `[a|(b;c)]` ... well, you get it.

Related to this is the use of the bar as an infix operator `('|')/2`.

With [ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995/Cor.2:2012](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iso-prolog/info), Technical Corrigendum 2, published 2012-02-15 the use of bar `|` as infix operator is now precisely defined. Prior to it, `|` had to be quoted. Here [is its draft](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#Res_A78).

Now, `'|'` can be defined as an infix operator but only with a priority above 1000. In this manner otherwise ambiguous cases as `[a|b|c]` remain syntactically invalid, but uses of `|` for DCGs and CHR are valid.

If you want to learn syntax by trying it out, the best is to use `writeq/1` and `write_canonical/1`.

The most conforming system w.r.t ISO-Prolog syntax is GNU Prolog.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't a statement, it's a term, and it doesn't imply anything at all about `a`, `b` or `c`. It just constructs an improper list.

To elaborate: The `[|]` syntax is actually syntactic sugar for the `.()` operator. Lists are internally constructed via `'.'(a,[])`, but since that becomes extremely tedious to type right away, you are allowed to write `[a]` instead. So the `.` operator is supposed to take a thing and a list and then contructs a longer list, but since there is no typing, nobody prevents you from applying it to two atoms, or any other pair of things. The result is a structure on which some list operations succeed and others fail. This is sometimes useful (think binary trees), but not as common as lists, therefore there is no special read syntax for it.

(Much the same happens with the `cons` operator in Lisp; if you google "improper list" you are liable to get many more results about Lisp, but the principle is exactly the same.)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Any chance you could give me a pointer on my second edit of the question, with `'|'`?

Comment: Yes, except that in SWI Prolog (and probably others) the second '|' isn't interpreted as '.'.